# Spring MVC Session Variable not declare as session variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm working on a Spring MVC project and I use thymeleaf for my html pages. I created a session variable in VariableSessionController. However when I call my session variable in my html pages with #session (for session variable in thymeleaf) it won't work. But it work if I call it as a model variable. Then I try to get my session variable after calling an other controller but he didn't find the resource I'm calling.

Here is my controller wher I create my session variable

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("country")
public class VariableSessionController extends AbstractController {

    @ModelAttribute("country")
    public Country country() {
       Country country = new Country();
       country.setCodeCountry("FR");
       return country;
    }
}
```

Here is where I call this controller.

```
@Controller
public class FrontpageController extends VariableSessionController {

    @Autowired
    private ConsulterInformationsFinancieres infosFinancieres;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String welcome(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("version","V1.1");
        return PageTemplates.INDEX;
    }

}
```

Here is the second controller I'm calling to try my session variable.

```
@Controller
public class AdvancedSearchController extends AbstractController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/recherche", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String init(@RequestParam Map<String, String> requestParams, Model model) {
        String debug = String.valueOf(model.containsAttribute("country"));
        logger.info(debug); // return false
        model.addAttribute("label", "label");
        return PageTemplates.ADVANCED_SEARCH;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: try implementing Serialziable in your Country class

Comment: Because that isn't what the `@SessionAttributes` is supposed to be used for. If you want to store stuff in the session globally then store it in the session yourself, don't try to abuse the `@SessionAttributes` for that. And instead of using a super class for that I suggest using a `@ControllerAdvice` or `HandlerInterceptor` for that.

Comment: Thanks for your response both :)
Deinum my problem is I'll get a code country from the first Url, after this I won't get it again then I can't create a controllerAdvice it'll change my session variable.